# Building a Digest Header for API request

Tags: rest, hash, base64, sha512

i've been struggling to wrap my head around something - https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3230#section-4.3.2
I'm trying to learn more about the API in general

To calculate the digest, you must do the following:

"SHA-512=" + Base64(SHA512(payload)
For an empty string, the output should be "SHA-512=z4PhNX7vuL3xVChQ1m2AB9Yg5AULVxXcg/SpIdNs6c5H0NE8XYXysP+DGNKHfuwvY7kxvUdBeoGlODJ6+SfaPg=="

I tried to do this for the empty payload but never came to the same conclusion..
Do I need to add something into the computation?
RFC 3230 - Instance Digests in HTTP
...
Instance Digests in HTTP (RFC 3230)
In the documentation I have explaining this example, we have this:

```
raw_payload = "{\"data\":{\"type\":\"customerAccessToken\",\"attributes\":{\"applicationCustomerReference\":\"15874569\"}}}"
digest = "SHA-512=" + BASE64(SHA512(raw_payload)
=> "SHA-512=z4PhNX7vuL3xVChQ1m2AB9Yg5AULVxXcg/SpIdNs6c5H0NE8XYXysP+DGNKHfuwvY7kxvUdBeoGlODJ6+SfaPg=="
```

Do I need to add something to the calculation instead of the just the empty string?
When I try to follow the example, the result is completely different - this is a calculation with an empty body.
Any help would be greatly appreciated :slight_smile: